# Basic Java method calling

Tags: java

I was browsing some classes that others had made and ran upon some code that looked like this:

```
public RationalNumber add(RationalNumber op2){
```

I'm familiar with calling methods such as `public int methodName();` with something like `object.methodName();` in the main code, but I'm not sure how to properly call a method like the one above. The full code for the program I was looking at can be referenced here: [Rational Number Class](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/222404-rational-numbers-class/)

I'm fairly new to Java so any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: When there is something so basic you don't understand, don't rely on Stackoverflow. Go to your notes, book, or online tutorials.

Comment: A class has a method that takes a parameter of the same class. Can you be a little more specific? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: if the method was `public int add (int inNumber) { ...` could you do it?

Comment: `object.methodName();` can't you at least substitute? when you do, you will have your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
public RationalNumber add(RationalNumber op2)
```

means that the method `add()` will return a `RationalNumber` object (note that `RationalNumber` is a class), and expects a `RationalNumber` object as parameter. So you would call it like:

```
RationalNumber num1 = new RationalNumber(...); // Initialize
RationalNumber num2 = new RationalNumber(...);
RationalNumber sum = new RationalNumber(...);

sum = num1.add(num2);
```

**Note** that `sum`, `num1` and `num2` are instances of the class `RationalNumber`. Since `add()` returns a `RationalNumber` object, you can assign its result to `sum` (which is of `RationalNumber` type).

Answer (score 2):

you can use following method for rational number is passed as a parameter.

```
 public RationalNumber add (RationalNumber op2)
   {
      int commonDenominator = denominator * op2.getDenominator();
      int numerator1 = numerator * op2.getDenominator();
      int numerator2 = op2.getNumerator() * denominator;
      int sum = numerator1 + numerator2;

      return new RationalNumber (sum, commonDenominator);
   }
```

Comment: Huh! you just copied and pasted the code from the link in the original question. The asker had already seen that. And you didn't answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
RationalNumber a = new RationalNumber(1,2);
RationalNumber b = new(RationalNumber(3,4);
RationalNumber sum = a.add(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

`RationalNumber abc = new RationalNumber( 2, 5);
RationalNumber xyz = new RationalNumber ( 3, 7);
RationalNumber resultOfAdd = abc.Add(xyz);`

Explanations:

First line creates a new instance of the class. Second line makes another instance.

Third line shows how to use the method.